# Angular 2 RC1 gives error for Zone on Firefox

Tags: angular

This is the errror I get on console. Any help would be appreciative.

Error: Zonehttp://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
    Zonehttp://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
    scheduleResolveOrReject/http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
    Zonehttp://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
    drainMicroTaskQueuehttp://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
    ZoneTask/this.invokehttp://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22

Answer (score 0):

Zone is a multi-threading implementation for JavaScript, which means that it can run multiple command threads (or tasks) asynchronously and simultaneously.. so when you have a zone error, this means that one of these threads might have encountered an error (looking for a value in a variable that has been destroyed, trying to access a template element that has been removed, an event listener that has not been cleared during the ngOnDestroy, etc..)

Unfortunately, Zone errors are not very informative, so you need to see what code has been (or should have been) running when the error has happened, and investigate there..